# LibUsbDotNet open device -> Device not found

Tags: c#, usb, libusb, libusbdotnet

I have usbasp programmer for AVR microcontrollers. This programmer uses libusb library. I've managed to connect it to pc, system detected new device and I managed to install driver for this device. It works well since I'm able to program AVR chips with it. So hardware part is 100% OK.

Now software part:
Using simple iterating over my libusb-win32 devices using LibUsbDotNet I find 2 devices. Both of them are named the same (and have same VID and PID) so I think this is composite device. Second one has some data in it. This is well shown on screenshots bellow.

[image: USB1]

[image: USB2]

[image: USB3]

And the code (it is just copy pasted from the examples)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using LibUsbDotNet;
using LibUsbDotNet.Info;
using LibUsbDotNet.Main;


namespace USB_Test_CLI_CS {
    class Program {

        public static readonly int VendorID = 0x16C0;
        public static readonly int ProductID = 0x05DC;

        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            UsbDevice usbDevice = null;

            UsbRegDeviceList allDevices = UsbDevice.AllDevices;

            Console.WriteLine("Found {0} devices", allDevices.Count);

            foreach (UsbRegistry usbRegistry in allDevices) {
                Console.WriteLine("Got device: {0}\r\n", usbRegistry.FullName);

                if (usbRegistry.Open(out usbDevice)) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Device Information\r\n------------------");

                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", usbDevice.Info.ToString());

                    Console.WriteLine("VID & PID: {0} {1}", usbDevice.Info.Descriptor.VendorID, usbDevice.Info.Descriptor.ProductID);

                    Console.WriteLine("\r\nDevice configuration\r\n--------------------");
                    foreach (UsbConfigInfo usbConfigInfo in usbDevice.Configs) {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", usbConfigInfo.ToString());

                        Console.WriteLine("\r\nDevice interface list\r\n---------------------");
                        IReadOnlyCollection<UsbInterfaceInfo> interfaceList = usbConfigInfo.InterfaceInfoList;
                        foreach (UsbInterfaceInfo usbInterfaceInfo in interfaceList) {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0}", usbInterfaceInfo.ToString());

                            Console.WriteLine("\r\nDevice endpoint list\r\n--------------------");
                            IReadOnlyCollection<UsbEndpointInfo> endpointList = usbInterfaceInfo.EndpointInfoList;
                            foreach (UsbEndpointInfo usbEndpointInfo in endpointList) {
                                Console.WriteLine("{0}", usbEndpointInfo.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    usbDevice.Close();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\r\n----- Device information finished -----\r\n");
            }



            Console.WriteLine("Trying to find our device: {0} {1}", VendorID, ProductID);
            UsbDeviceFinder usbDeviceFinder = new UsbDeviceFinder(VendorID, ProductID);

            // This does not work !!! WHY ?
            usbDevice = UsbDevice.OpenUsbDevice(usbDeviceFinder);

            if (usbDevice != null) {
                Console.WriteLine("OK");
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("FAIL");
            }

            UsbDevice.Exit();

            Console.Write("Press anything to close");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Here's output of this program

```
Found 2 devices
Got device: Van Ooijen Technische Informatica - USBasp


----- Device information finished -----

Got device: Van Ooijen Technische Informatica - USBasp

Device Information
------------------
Length:18
DescriptorType:Device
BcdUsb:0x0110
Class:VendorSpec
SubClass:0x00
Protocol:0x00
MaxPacketSize0:8
VendorID:0x16C0
ProductID:0x05DC
BcdDevice:0x0103
ManufacturerStringIndex:1
ProductStringIndex:2
SerialStringIndex:0
ConfigurationCount:1
ManufacturerString:www.fischl.de
ProductString:USBasp
SerialString:

VID & PID: 5824 1500

Device configuration
--------------------
Length:9
DescriptorType:Configuration
TotalLength:18
InterfaceCount:1
ConfigID:1
StringIndex:0
Attributes:0x80
MaxPower:25
ConfigString:


Device interface list
---------------------
Length:9
DescriptorType:Interface
InterfaceID:0
AlternateID:0
EndpointCount:0
Class:PerInterface
SubClass:0x00
Protocol:0x00
StringIndex:0
InterfaceString:


Device endpoint list
--------------------

----- Device information finished -----

Trying to find our device: 5824 1500
FAIL
Press anything to close
```

What I'd like to get is this simple code to detect this device which IS present (since simple iteration over all devices finds it and other tool "USB Cfg Interrogator" find it too).
This has been asked before but there were no constructive answer.

I also could use libusb-win32 c++ library and create some C# wrappers for it but if it is not needed and I can use LibUsbDotNet library I'd like to use it instead of creating wrappers myself.

Comment: libUSB is suitable for USB devices that don't have a device driver.  You can open it and make low-level USB bus transfers to talk to the device.  Glorified serial port, really.  Problem is, you already have a device driver for it, USBasp, and it has already opened the device.  You'll have to disable it.

Comment: Could you tell me how? I can disable the device in the device manager but this will disable it in the list I showed and there will be 0 found devices instead of 2 which show up now. Also according to LibUsbDotNet documentation, the device needs to be connected AND have driver installed to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'd like to get is this simple code to detect this device which IS present

You almost have that already. There is only one for which `usbRegistry.Open()` actually works.
There should be no other device - check that your use latest libusb-win32 version (`1.2.6.0` at this time).

`UsbDeviceFinder` seems to have a problem with this phantom device.

Answer (score 0):

You may try filter wizard to install device filter.